# Unsure of an implicit differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I don't want a full solution per se, just an appropriate hint/guidance to nudge me in the right direction if possible.

The problem at hand: $$(dy+dx)^3 = 27(x+y)^2(dx)^3$$

Thus far I've tried using a substitution $z=\frac{dy}{dx}$, and since $zdx=dy$ I'm able to simplify the expression to the following: $$(z+1)^3=27(x+y)^2\\$$ But this results in quite a hairy integral equation, dependent on both x and y, when I try solving for z, which leads me to believe that I am missing some detail (and gauging from previous experience, most likely a very obvious one).

Update: I thought of letting $v=x+y$. Thus $dv=1+\frac{dy}{dx}=z+1$ which has lead to finding one answer, that being $$y+x = (x+c)^3$$

Comment: $(1+y')^3=(x+y)'^3=(x+y)^2$

Comment: If I am not wrong you should see the first equation as: the unknown is $y = y(x)$ which is a scalar function, function of $x$. The your equation reads $(y'(x) + 1)^3 = 27(x + y(x))^2$. Then you can take the cubic square root, get a normal ODE, and hopefully solve for $y = y(x)$. I don't see a good reason for this ODE to have an explicit solution, but I am not very good at computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1+y')^3=(x+y)'^3=27(x+y)^2$$
Try to substitute $u=x+y$:
$$u'^3=27u^2$$
Consider two cases
$$u=x+y=0 \implies y=-x$$
This is a solution of the DE. And $u\ne 0$ gives another solution.
$$\int \dfrac {du}{u^{2/3}}=3\int dx$$

Comment: Thank you.  It did the trick.  According to the answers for the problem, there is a second solution as well $y=-x$, would it be a "by-product" of using the mentioned substitution?

Comment: Yes because you need to divide by $u=y+x$ to separate and solve the DE so you suppose $y \ne -x$ which is another solution @TempraTura